# Empty EventName in Interaction EventTrigger

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dockpanel

Consider the following code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger>
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    …
```

As `EventTrigger` does not have `EventName` property set, what events will it handle? It is handling something definitely because I see that this command is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Command` gets called when the `Loaded` event occurs.

If we look at the source code of the EventTrigger class, we can see that the DependencyProperty `EventNameProperty` has `Loaded` as its default value.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty EventNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventName", typeof (string), typeof (EventTrigger), (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object) "Loaded", new PropertyChangedCallback(EventTrigger.OnEventNameChanged)));
```

Comment: And this is the answer I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code will fire your Command as `DockPanel.Loaded` event.

Comment: Why? Is there any reference? How to prove that?